# Find the difference between two timestamps while considering the id of the rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

So basically I have a table in **MySQL**:

```
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID        | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Query     | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And the ID represents a user id, the queries represent a query that he gives to a machine and timestamp when he gives. I am trying to find the sessions that a user could have with the machine, by checking each record of the table and comparing the current timestamp with the previous one. If the difference is below a threshold of 300 seconds then I consider it a session.

However, this way I do not take into consideration that the same user might be using the machine multiple times. How can I also check if the previous ID is the same with the current ID of the record that I am checking?

I have been searching around the internet and this is what I have come up with so far.

```
select Count(*) from(
select  t.*,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, @prevQT, `timestamp`) as session,
    @prevQT:=t.`timestamp`
    from myTable t,
    (select @prevQT:=(Select min(`timestamp`) from myTable)) vars
    ORDER BY ID) subquery_alias
    where session < 300;
```

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Sample Data:

```
1 , "google"        , '2013-08-02 08:58:06'
1 , "dogs"          , '2013-08-02 09:00:09'
1 , "dogs and cats" , '2013-08-02 09:02:02'
1 , "toys"          , '2013-08-02 09:10:09'
1 , "games for kids", '2013-08-02 09:12:25'
2 , "football"      , '2013-08-02 09:12:28'
2 , "manchester"    , '2013-08-02 09:14:37'
2 , "championship"  , '2013-08-02 09:17:48'
3 , "flowers"       , '2013-08-02 09:20:31'
```

Applying the query on it, the result should be 4, since the user with ID 1 used the machine twice with a time difference more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Please provide sample data (covering all cases) and the desired result.

Comment: @PM77-1 just updated my question :)